Lee's Riemannian Manifolds problem 4-1
I am trying to solve (Lee's RM problem 4-1):
Let $M \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be an embedded submanifold and $Y \in \mathcal{X}(M)$. For every point $p \in M$ and vector $v \in T_p M$, define $\nabla_v^\top Y$ by (4.4).
Let us define the tangential directional derivative of $Y$ in the direction $v$ to be:
$
\nabla_v^\top Y = \pi^\top \left( \nabla_v \widetilde{Y} \right). \tag{4.4}
$
(a) Show that $\nabla_v^\top Y$ does not depend on the choice of extension $\widetilde{Y}$ of $Y$.
[Hint: Use Prop. A.28.]
My try:
To prove that $ \nabla^\top_v Y $ is independent of the choice of extension $ \widetilde{Y} $
Let $ \widetilde{Y}_1 $ and $ \widetilde{Y}_2 $ be any two smooth extensions of $ Y $ to a neighborhood of $ M $ in $ \mathbb{R}^n $. Define $ W = \widetilde{Y}_1 - \widetilde{Y}_2 $. Then $ W $ is a smooth vector field on $ \mathbb{R}^n $ such that $ W_p = 0 $ for all $ p \in M $, since both $ \widetilde{Y}_1 $ and $ \widetilde{Y}_2 $ agree with $ Y $ on $ M $.
Consider $ \nabla_{\widetilde{v}} W $ at $ p \in M $, where $ \widetilde{v} $ is any smooth extension of $ v \in T_p M $. The difference between the covariant derivatives is:
$
\nabla_{\widetilde{v}} \widetilde{Y}_1 - \nabla_{\widetilde{v}} \widetilde{Y}_2 = \nabla_{\widetilde{v}} W.
$
We need to show that $ \pi^\top \left( \nabla_{\widetilde{v}} W \big|_p \right) = 0 $. Since $ W $ vanishes on $ M $, its derivative $ \nabla_{\widetilde{v}} W \big|_p $ lies in the normal space $ N_p M $ of $ M $ at $ p $.
By Proposition A.28, for any function $ f \in C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n) $ with $ f \big|_M = 0 $, we have $ v(f) = 0 $ for all $ v \in T_p M $. Since the components of $ W $ vanish on $ M $, their derivatives along $ v $ also vanish. Thus, the tangential component of $ \nabla_{\widetilde{v}} W \big|_p $ is zero.
Therefore:
$
\pi^\top \left( \nabla_{\widetilde{v}} \widetilde{Y}_1 \big|_p \right) = \pi^\top \left( \nabla_{\widetilde{v}} \widetilde{Y}_2 \big|_p \right),
$
which means $ \nabla^\top_v Y $ does not depend on the choice of extension $ \widetilde{Y} $.

I would appreciate your feedback. Is this correct?. Otherwise how would I fix it?
